# Is there Pivot feature in IBM DB2 9.7 ?

Tags: db2, pivot

I want to know whether there exists a pivot feature in IBM DB2 because I get an exception that it doesn't exists .. If it doesn't exist in DB2 , is there any other way to achieve pivot in IBM DB2 ?

I'm using IBM DB2 9.7 version.

Comment: Have you done any research?  This is a Frequently Asked Question.

Answer (score -1):

There is no inbuilt pivot feature in db2 like SQL Server.

However you can achieve pivot using **DECODE** function in db2.

Check this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en) for further Information on how to achieve Pivot Functionality using **DECODE** function